# Why does my USB device not get recognized by Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, wifi

I seem to have a problem that no else appears to have encountered before (at least a couple of hours Googling has shown this to be the case).

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I plug in the device (Linksys AE3000) and type `lsusb` in the terminal, but the device name doesn't show up at all. I have attempted to plug it into different USB ports, all of which work, and the device fails to be recognized.

Now, I know the device works on this computer, because it also runs Windows with which the device works perfectly fine.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Many hardware problems can be solved by updating kernel, as each minor release can bring better support for hundreds of device.Check your kernel version with `uname -r` and see if the latest version can detect your device.

Comment: @AdityaPatil Turns out in the process of trying to make it work on Ubuntu, something happened to the device because it actually is no longer being recognized on Windows or any other machine I have. I have no idea what could cause that to happen...

Comment: How would I even go about fixing the device?! Nothing recognizes it anymore.

Comment: The device **name** doesn't show up, but does the device show up? Compare the output of `lsusb` before and after plugging it in. It's possible that the exact device model isn't recognized, but you might still be able to use it, perhaps after informing the driver that it's compatible with some earlier model. Have you checked the status of this device's support under Linux?

Comment: @Gilles Yeah, the outputs don't differ. The device appears not to be supported.